# How to power on a computer after a power failure?

Tags: power-supply, wake-on-lan, ups, wake-up, arduino

**Background**

I have a Ubiquiti Network Video Recorder (NVR) connected to an Eaton 3S 550 UPS. The NVR is basically a tiny PC running Debian, which records video from network cameras on the LAN. My goal is to always keep the NVR running, or if there is a power failure to shut it down properly.

Shutting it down properly turned out to be doable by installing NUT (Network Up Tools) which automatically issues a shutdown command when the UPS reaches 60% battery. The UPS is connected by USB to the NVR.

Turning it back on also turned out to be easy by setting the BIOS of the NVR to "Power on" on "AC connected". And since the UPS will automatically kill power to the mains outputs after the NVR has shut down (it detects this via USB), when the power comes back the UPS will switch on power to the mains output and the NVR will boot back up.

**The Problem**

However, there is one tricky scenario that I can't figure out how to handle. Imagine there is a power failure, the UPS battery reaches 60% and the NVR starts shutting down (which takes about 20-40 seconds). If the power comes back while the NVR is still shutting down, it will of course finish shutting down and power itself off - but since the UPS didn't turn off its mains output yet, the "AC connected" event won't occur, and the NVR will stay off. The only way to power it up again would be to manually press the power button or if there is another power failure long enough for the UPS to turn its mains output off , and then on when the power comes back.
How would one solve this?

**What I've tried so far**

I've played around with Wake On LAN, which is available in the BIOS but doesn't seem to work in real life (the ethernet port doesn't even have a light on when the NVR is powered off). My thinking was that some device, perhaps just a simple dedicated Arduino connected to mains (not on the UPS) could issue a WOL to the NVR either when it powers on or periodically every minute or so.

The "brute force" solution would be to build an Arduino rig with a servo that can push the power button on the NVR - which might work but be quite clumsy and a hassle to get right. The NVR is as mentioned a tiny PC running Debian, and I really want to avoid messing around with trying to open it up and connecting anything (e.g. an Arduino) straight to the power button solder points...

**The Question**

What other tricks could I try to either prevent this scenario from happening or to resolve it?

Comment: Your brute force solution wouldn't need to mechanically push the button; it could just temporarily short the same contacts the button does when pushed.  I didn't follow the logic of your problem case, though.  The UPS doesn't use feedback from the computer, and doesn't stop power to the outlets unless it exhausts its battery.  You may be thinking through the theoretical possibilities you need to cover, and might be worrying about a condition that won't happen as you envision it.  BTW, you've got two TL;DR, but no sign of a brief summary.

Comment: @fixer1234 The UPS does turn itself off after its clients are done shutting down, this is a behavior that can't be turned off because exhausting the battery will shorten its life span. I specifically mention that I don't want to open the NVR and messa around with the internals, i.e. _"short the same contacts the button does when pushed"_. Finally, I've simulated the scenario and it indeed happens as described, it's not just based on some loose theory.

Comment: Exhausting the battery after the load has been shut off isn't typically an issue because when the load shuts off, power is no longer being drained.  I wasn't familiar with any UPS that stops power to the outlets by design.  What would be the power source when you want to turn the NVR back on (the UPS needs to have active outlets first)?  Also, the Problem section isn't clear.  Why does the AC Connected event rely on the state of the UPS outlets.  I could see the possibility, though, of it being sent while the NVR was powering off, so the NVR doesn't deal with it.  (cont'd)

Comment: And it doesn't get sent again when the NVR is ready to listen.  One other thought.  It's NUT that interprets all of the data coming over the USB connection, and that only works inside the OS when powered on.  When powered off, the USB ports have pretty limited capability, if any.  Can it even do things like WOL?  My suspicion is that you won't be able to restart via the USB port, even if the UPS sent the AC Connected signal at a time the NVR could use it.  It might be worth investigating why WOL on Ethernet isn't working.  (cont'd)

Comment: That's really the existing provision for powering on via external signal.  If you can't use that and don't want to mess with the inards, your brute force solution is the obvious choice.  It could probably be simpler, though -- just a solenoid to push the button with a few relays and minor circuitry to handle the logic of pushing once, only when the NVR is off and the wall outlet (or probably rather the UPS outlet), has power.

Comment: Issues I can think of with WOL.... `1.` Usually you need UDP port 9 to be allowed to make it to the machine network and it is a broadcast so by default going across different subnets, you may have issues if any routers between do not route the broadcast traffic with ip-helper, etc. `2.` The OS level NIC in addition to the BIOS WOL support options need to be enabled `3.` If the OS is shutdown but goes into a deep hibernate or sleep mode rather than a true shutdown, the WOL packet may still not wake up the machine, it needs to be truly powered off..... Things to think about.

Comment: For the traffic UDP port 9 part of it, run a network capture on the machine while it is ON, then send the UDP WOL traffic to the machine with it being powered ON, and then stop the trace and inspect to see if you see that it sees the UDP port 9 traffic. If not, then figure out the network or confirm the WOL tool you are using is sending it properly. If the machine does see the UDP traffic, look over the OS level settings as per the things mentioned above. Make sure the app or whatever that sends the WOL is using the correct MAC, IP, & subnet mask addresses too. Quick thoughts from experience.

Comment: Lastly after reading some of the comments above, there are programmable switches that you could plug the machine into that will allow Ethernet connection, and programmatically have it kill power at that level to the server when the UPS has an event and wait X amount of seconds before trying to power back on I suppose or something along those lines.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Thanks, I'll look into the UDP port issue with regards to Wake On LAN. I was under the impression that I wouldn't need to do any particular setup on the router as long as both sender and receiver are on the same subnet?

Comment: Correct, if on the same subnet, then there should not be any need to redirect broadcast traffic so you should be fine. I'd still sniff/trace it to confirm it sees it to ensure the WOL client tool you are using to send the magic packet or whatever it really doing what you expect it to do. Again, be sure you have the correct MAC address, IP address, and using the correct subnet mask to the correct client machine when sending it to the packet to wake it up. Not sure how your IP assignments are handled such as DHCP, etc. and the arp cache of the OS for the WOL app you are sending it from.